# How to configure sending errors by e-mail with Symfony 5.1, Monolog and Mailer component?

Tags: symfony, mailer, monolog

Do you have an example configuration to send logs by email with the Mailer component of Symfony 5.1.

In the Symfony blog we announce this feature, but I can't put the right config in monolog.yaml

https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-misc-improvements-part-3 :
That's why in Symfony 5.1 we added a new Monolog log handler which uses the Mailer component to send the logs via email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this addition only covers the actuall `MailerHandler` class in the `monolog-bridge`. This does not cover the possibility to configure it in the `monolog-bundle` (that's the drawback if those components are distributed over multiple packages).

The PR for the change in the `monolog-bundle` is still open, and can be found here: [Add Symfony Mailer support #354](https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/pull/354).

If you don't want to wait for the change in the monolog-bundle you could already use it by defining the handler as a service and then using it with the `service` type in the monolog configuration.

So define your service:

```
services:
    # this configures the "mail" as a prototype, so you can
    # define the sender and recipient mail addresses here
    symfony_mailer_service_template:
        class: Symfony\Component\Mime\Email
        calls:
            - ['from', ['webapp@example.com']]
            - ['to', ['ops@example.com']]
            - ['subject', ['Logs']]

    symfony_mailer_service:
        class: Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\MailerHandler
        arguments:
            - '@mailer.mailer'
            - '@symfony_mailer_service_template'
            - !php/const Monolog\Logger::DEBUG # log level
            - true # bubble
```

And then in your mailer configuration you could use it like this:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: fingers_crossed
            handler: deduplicated

        deduplicated:
            type:    deduplication
            handler: symfony_mailer

        symfony_mailer:
            type: service
            id: symfony_mailer_service
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm. Except the message template: it is very scarce now and there is no stacktrace. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: @VladimirShevelyov did you find how to replicate the swift_mailer message template?